# order by dates that match criteria

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, subquery

I have the following query that outputs the users that received the highest number of favorites in the past week in descending order:

```
SELECT COUNT(faves.user_id) AS topFaves, faves.created_on, user_name 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN faves ON faves.user_id= users.id 
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= created_on 
GROUP BY id ORDER BY topFaves DESC
```

I would like to be able to extend this list to contain all users, not just from the past week, but still order them by the same criteria (the number of favorites they got in the past week and not by the number of faves they have in total). 
I tried to include a subquery in the select but didnt have any luck with it.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: does above query working ?? please  elaborate more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but just delete this line:

```
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= created_on
```

And you'll have "all users" - still sorting by topFaves...

Also if you want to list everyone (not just 10 people), you'll need to delete:

```
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to list all users but still sort them by the number of faves they received in the past week and not by the number of faves they have in total..

Comment: @Jack - ok, so is `created_on` in your `users` table or your `faves` table?  In your WHERE clause, you don't specify. This could be your answer.

Comment: created_on field is in the faves table. How should I change the WHERE clause then?

Comment: @Jack What about this:  `SELECT COUNT(faves.user_id) AS topFaves, faves.created_on, user_name 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN faves ON faves.user_id= users.id 
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= faves.created_on 
GROUP BY id ORDER BY topFaves DESC`  Correct me if I'm wrong, but the LEFT join will take all from users table, and count up your WHERE clause accordingly.  I would make sure you specify faves.created_on - not just "created_on"

Comment: ok, now it gives me the number of faves each user got the past week but still I dont get users who got zero faves this week. You see this is my problem, that once I restrict the WHERE to the past week, it filters out the rest..

Comment: @Jack - Oh, yea.  Just delete the where clause entirely.  It's useless in this scenerio, but use the LEFT join as I specified.

Comment: But then it will not sort the users by the number of faves they got this week which is what I need. Instead, it will sort them by the number of faves they got ever..

Comment: @Jack ahhh....  how about this then: `SELECT COUNT(faves.user_id) AS topFaves, faves.created_on, user_name FROM users LEFT JOIN faves ON (faves.user_id= users.id AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= faves.created_on) GROUP BY id ORDER BY topFaves DESC`  See if that works... I can't remember if that's allowed or not though.

Comment: Right now the query returns the "topFaves" alias which is the number of faves the user got this week. What if I also want to return the number of faves that user got ever? Will I need a different query for that or can I add it to this one?
By the way, I accepted the answer but the +1 doesnt work for me because I dont have enough points yet...